# Why does device use not existing API?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have small app. It has [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getMaxNumPictureInPictureActions()) that has been added in 26 API level.

```
...
getMaxNumPictureInPictureActions();
...
```

When i run it on device that has 24 API level, the app crashes. It's ok. Then i deleted that method and tried to use [constant](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#BIND_AUTOFILL_SERVICE) which has been added in 26 API level as well.

```
...
String s = Manifest.permission.BIND_AUTOFILL_SERVICE;
...
```

For some reason, after reading this line, the app doesn't crash.

**Why it doesn't happen? 24 level doesn't have that constant and that's why this app must crash, mustn't it ?**

Comment: Constants are compiled into the code as their value. Methods that are part of the SDK are supposed to be implemented on-device so it doesn't get compiled into the APK.

Comment: Note that just because it doesn't crash, doesn't mean it'll do what you want it to do. If that constant means something else in an older API, you've probably introduced a bug.